# In a trace how do I capture parameter values for event class 44 SP:StmtStarting?

Tags: sql-server

In my trace I see stored procedures calls in my text data like this:

```
EXEC SomeStoredProcedure, @Param1, @Param2
```

How can I capture the values of those parameters?

This is for event class

- 44 SP:StmtStarting
- 45 SP:StmtCompleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these SP calls within an SP?

The Stmt events are statements within the procedure.

Look at the RPC:Completed: [SQL Server Profile - View Parameter Values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357283/sql-server-profile-view-parameter-values) or 43:SP:Completed