# Fastest way to find which parameters are passed when the code is running without using debug method?

Tags: sql

I have execution of stored procedures buried so deep in code it would take some time to debug through the code for errors. I was wondering what is the fastest way to determine which parameters are passed to a stored procedure when the code is running without using debug?
This is in SQl server 2005.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357283/sql-server-profile-view-parameter-values

Comment: Debug, or print. That's what comes to my mind first. I recommend printing out the thing/s you want to examine, you can easily do that in code part, in database part, use log files for errors. Don't really an expert in that area, I can recommend this link: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1021/sql-server-2005-log-file-viewer/